# Nested Structure issue

Tags: c, structure

How to create array of nodes in the structure.
I uploaded my sample.

```
 struct timebasedSpecificTimesIntervalNode
 {
   int hrs;
   int min;
   int sec;
 };

 struct timebasedSpecificTimesInterval
 {
     struct timebasedSpecificTimesIntervalNode* nodes;
     int count;
     char *cFilePath;
 };
```

How to create array of nodes for this structure timebasedSpecificTimesInterval.

```
  struct timebasedSpecificTimesInterval specificTimes;
```

How to create array of 3 nodes to this structure.

**EDIT**

create structure for this values

```
  hrs:5,2,3 min 23,58,4 sec 54,12,2
```

Thnks

Comment: struct timebasedSpecificTimesInterval specificTimes[3]???

Comment: @OAOD: actually timebasedSpecificTimesInterval shouldnot be an array.only NODES inside the timebasedSpecificTimesInterval should be an array.

Comment: It is still not clear from your question exactly what you are trying to achieve. static initialization, at run time, exactly 3, or could it be more (or less)?

Comment: `struct timebasedSpecificTimesIntervalNode
 {
   int hrs[3]; ...`

Comment: Every time you type timebasedSpecificTimesInterval, God kills a kitten.

Comment: @Nico:It could be more.not exactly 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main(void) {
    struct timebasedSpecificTimesInterval data;
    data.count = 3;
    data.nodes = malloc(data.count * sizeof *data.nodes);
    data.cFilePath = NULL;
    if (data.nodes) {

        data.nodes[0].hrs = 5; data.nodes[0].min = 23; data.nodes[0].sec = 54;
        data.nodes[1].hrs = 2; data.nodes[1].min = 58; data.nodes[1].sec = 12;
        data.nodes[2].hrs = 3; data.nodes[2].min = 4;  data.nodes[2].sec = 2;
        /* use data */

        free(data.nodes);
        data.nodes = NULL; /* optional */
        data.count = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: used example provided in OP

Comment: @ pmg:Can u assign those hrs,sec,min into this structure.That will be helpful for me.

Comment: I've ninja edited my post once I saw your edit. Hopefully it is useful to you now ...

Comment: @ pmg:Thanks a lot.This is what I actually want..+1 for your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. Unless I have completely the wrong end of the stick. I am not a fan of the new struct keyword littering my code.

```
typedef struct 
 {
   int hrs;
   int min;
   int sec;
 } timebasedSpecificTimesIntervalNode;

 typedef struct 
 {
     timebasedSpecificTimesIntervalNode* nodes;
     int count;
     char *cFilePath;
 } timebasedSpecificTimesInterval;

int main (void)
{
  timebasedSpecificTimesIntervalNode nodeArray[3];  
  timebasedSpecificTimesInterval specificTimesInterval;

  //initialise the pointer
  specificTimesInterval.nodes = nodeArray;

  // you can now access the pointer as an array
  nodeArray[0].hrs = 3; //arbitrary value

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question... just like you would any other array:

```
struct timebasedSpecificTimesInterval specificTimes[3];
```